# Public network in vagrant

Tags: networking, ip, vagrant, virtualbox, public

I Need to setup 2 vagrant machine with public network,so follow this link to https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/networking/public_network.html edit the Vagrantfile.

But only one machine only have public static ip. another one **not** get public static ip.

this is my vagrant machine configuration:

**Machine 1 Vagrant File:**

```
    Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

      config.vm.box = "man2"

      config.ssh.username = "vagrant"
      config.vm.hostname = "www.myhost.net"
      config.ssh.forward_agent = "true"


      config.vm.network "public_network", ip: "192.168.1.10"

      config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
        vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "2048"]
      end
      config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", :mount_options => ["dmode=777","fmode=666"] 
    end
```

**Machine 2 Vagrant File:**

```
        Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

          config.vm.box = "man1"
          config.ssh.username = "vagrant"
          config.vm.hostname = "www.myhost.net"
          config.ssh.forward_agent = "true"

         config.vm.network "public_network", ip: "192.168.1.20"

           config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
            vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "2048"]
          end

           config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", :mount_options => ["dmode=777","fmode=777"]

        end
```

While **Vagrant up**

System Ask **Which interface should the network bridge to?**

I Choose Both machie as 1 "**eno1**"

```
        1) eno1
        2) docker0
        3) veth54294ac
        4) virbr0
        5) vethc81d7f7
        6) br-08179b343476
        7) br-1d45dec94893
        ==> default: When choosing an interface, it is usually the one that is
        ==> default: being used to connect to the internet.
            default: Which interface should the network bridge to? 1
```

then, **Vagrant ssh** Both machine

only one machine have public static ip , another machine doesn't  show public ip.

if I choose **Different Bridge network** in any one system  some think like: (machine 2) to

```
        1) eno1
        2) docker0
        3) veth54294ac
        4) virbr0
        5) vethc81d7f7
        6) br-08179b343476
        7) br-1d45dec94893
```

option: 4 (**virbro**) ot others now, also same issue.

**Update 1:**

Before I tried Same Setup its working fine, only different Version of **Vagrant** and **VirtualBox**

**Before Tried:**

Fedrora 23

Vagrant 1.8.1

virtualbox 5.0

**Now tried:**

Fedrora 23

Vagrant 1.8.6

Virtualbox 5.1.6

Any Restrictions in this versions.

Why?

System cannot share same Bridge network ?

Suggest me how to resolve this problem.

Comment: you want the same hostname for both machines ? not sure you can do that, change the hostname of one of your machine

Comment: @FrédéricHenri  Same Setup(hostnames are same),  I tried Before its working fine , But now only have this problem.

Comment: @FrédéricHenri I update my question please review this

Comment: @FrédéricHenri  After Change My hostname, still have same issue Suggest me any other way to did this.

Comment: I am wondering about down-vote, suggest me what I did wrong, I need to edit my question or solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Your `Vagrantfile` seems good to me. It may be your `Machine2` IP `192.168.1.20` is assigned to other system. if assigned to other system then DHCP will not assign this IP to your machine. 
if you are sure these IPs not assigned to other system then make it `static` otherwise you can give like :

```
config.vm.network "public_network"
```

in This case DHCP will release IP that is available.

No need to write separate `Vagrantfile` for each VM. you can create a single `Vagrantfile` for multiple VM like:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do  |config|                                                       

    config.vm.define :server1 do |server1|
             server1.vm.box = "man1"      
             server1.vm.host_name = "vm1.example.com"
             server1.vm.network "public_network", ip: "192.168.1.10"
             server1.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", :mount_options => ["dmode=777","fmode=666"]
             server1.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
                   vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "2048"]
            end    
    end

    config.vm.define :server2 do |server2|
             server2.vm.box = "man1"      
             server2.vm.host_name = "vm2.example.com"
             server2.vm.network "public_network", ip: "192.168.1.20"
             server2.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", :mount_options => ["dmode=777","fmode=666"]
             server2.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
                   vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "2048"]
            end
    end
end
```

if you want to up `server1` then do

```
vagrant up server1
```

To up all VM then do

```
vagrant up
```

For ssh use like:

```
vagrant ssh server1
```

> System cannot share same Bridge network ?

yes , it can share bridge network. you can create multiple VM with single bridge.

For more info you can refer [Documentation](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/)