# Two vagrantfiles - VMs communication

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, virtualbox

I have a quite old VM instantiated via Vagrant. I have all my dev stack on it. The configuration is this one:

```
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 3389, host: 33389, id: "rdp", auto_correct: true
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"
  config.vm.hostname = "labs"
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.memory = "4096"
    vb.name = "labs"
  end
```

I have generated a new VM for testing via Vagrant as well, but using another Vagrantfile. The configuration is this one:

```
s2.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
s2.vm.hostname = 'backend'
s2.vm.box_url = "ubuntu/precise64"

s2.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.56.102"
s2.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 22, host: 10222, id: "ssh"

s2.vm.provider :virtualbox do |v|
  v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnshostresolver1", "on"]
  v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", 1024]
  v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--name", "backend"]
end
```

On this server, I have a mongodb that I'd like to connect to, from my first VM.

What are the change I could bring to the second VagrantFile to make the VM accessible to the first one ?

Or, is there another more obvious and simpler solution

Answer (score 3):

you can change ip address of second `Vagrantfile` to some other ip which is in network of first VM.
you can change below line in second `Vagrantfile`:

```
s2.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.56.102"
```

to

```
s2.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.33.11"
```

you can assign any free ip in this network so you will be able to ping vm each other.

**Note :** 
No need to create multiple `Vagrantfile` for multiple vm . you can create a single `Vagrantfile` for all. you can refer my another answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39805654/5035803) to create single `Vagrantfile`.